# How to disable web security (cross origin reequest) in webkit gtk

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pygobject

I'm trying to write a site specific browser for a few sites and am facing an issue with webkitgtk. WebKitGtk blocks some cross domain request as a security measure and there is no way to disable it in the WebKitGtk API

Python simple example

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit
window = Gtk.Window()
webview = WebKit.WebView()
webview.load_uri('http://drive.google.com')
window.add(webview)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Output:

```
  ** Message: console message:  @0: Unable to post message to https://0.drive.google.com. Recipient has origin https://drive.google.com.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible as of now. Bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58378

Answer (score 0):

The only setting that appears relevant to me is `enable-xss-auditor`:

```
settings = WebKit.WebSettings()
settings.set_property('enable-xss-auditor', False)
webview.set_settings(settings)
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for my own implementation, and while WebKit itself has an option to disable web security (`Settings::setWebSecurityEnabled`) it's not exposed to the GTK+ API.