# Accessing a web server from a webkit client written in haskell reflex-dom

Tags: haskell, webkit, gtk3, webkitgtk, reflex

This is a follow up question to [Acess a servant server with a reflex-dom client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143155/acess-a-servant-server-with-a-reflex-dom-client):

If I run the client code in a web browser everything works fine.
However if I run the client code in webkit under gtk3 (and Debian), I can see the request in the server, but the client doesn't receive any response.

I assume, this is again some kind of a security or CORS problem. I found this post [How to disable web security (cross origin reequest) in webkit gtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252206/how-to-disable-web-security-cross-origin-reequest-in-webkit-gtk) from the year 2012 saying *not possible* due to this bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58378. If I look at this bug, it says: *Status: RESOLVED FIXED*. The second answer of the mentiond SO post shows some settings in an unspecified file..

My question is: **Where** (directory and file) do I have to specify **what**, to access a server from a WebkitGtk client.

Comment: what version of webkit are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Debian packages *libwebkitgtk3.0* *-common -amd64* and *-dev*. The Debain package version is 2.4.9. Haskell Cabal packages are *webkitgtk3-0.14.2.1* and *webkitgtk3-javascriptcore-0.13.2.0*.

Comment: I have found another version number: When I access the server from the webkit client, the server says: *"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/538.15 GHCJS"*. So the Webkit version seems to be **538.15**.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same problem.

Comment: @Schoon: Unfortunately, the answer is "No". However I have to say, the last year I didn't do any client server development